# Can a private on-premise network access GAE Flex via Cloud VPN?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I was wondering if a site-to-site VPN setup like the one in this diagram is possible:

[image]

From the diagram, I could access the GAE Flex instance's internal IP that are launched in the VPC from the on-premise server, but I don't think I could invoke a *.appspot.com URL without needing to go outside of the tunnel, correct?

The on-premise network can only whitelist IP ranges for external HTTPS access but it seems like GAE can't support such a configuration?

Is this kind of setup only possible by setting up a GCE reverse proxy? If that's the case, would I just be better off deploying my application as a Kubernetes cluster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I did an experiment that revealed several things about this setup in case any is interested in this in the future:

1. In the above diagram, under the assumption that the on-premise instances are in a private subnet with no external IP, they can reach app engine instances via their internal IP.
2. Just because they can reach the App Engine flexible instances via their internal IP, this doesn't mean that they can then be port forwarded to invoke your function.
3. The only real use case for App Engine flex working with Cloud VPN is if you need the App Engine instances to be able to reach either your private cloud and/or on-premise instances i.e. going from right to left in the above diagram.